# Magento 2 : There is Different Class for When User Logs Out Due to Inactivity

Tags: magento2, customer, redirect, logout

I need to redirect customer to a different URL when is logged out automaticly.

I made a prefence for `Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Logout` but it looks like, when the customer is logged out due to inactivity my prefrence does not run.